# Continuity of an integral with a removably discontinuous integrand

Tags: integration, functions, continuity

Say I have a function $f_c:[0,\ell]\to\mathbb{R}$, where $c\in K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, with $K$ compact.  For every choice of $c$, $f_c$ is continuous everywhere except at some $s_c\in[0,\ell]$, where there is a removable discontinuity.  Define the function
$$
F(c)=\int_0^\ell f_c(s)\,ds.
$$
Can I say that $F$ is continuous?  If so, what's the best way to do this?

I've tried to brute force this using the formulas I have for $f_c$, but it quickly became quite terrible.  I've also considered thinking of $f_c(s)$ as $f(s,c)$ so that I could "fill" the removable discontinuities, but I'm unsure that I can do this, since there are uncountably many on $[0,\ell]\times K$.

[Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313254/removing-removable-discontinuities-in-riemann-integration).

Comment: There is no hope of anything like this unless you know $f_c(x)$ is also continuous as a function of $c$ or something like that...

Comment: $f_c(s)$ is continuous in $c$, provided that we are avoiding $s_c$.  (Since $f_c(s_c)$ is a removable discontinuity.)

Comment: @AegisCruiser for a fixed $s$, "$f_c(s)$ is continuous in $c$" means: "the map $c \mapsto f_c(s)$ is continuous". Is this what you meant in your last comment? If it is true that for almost every $s \in [0,\ell]$, $f_c(s)$ is continuous in $c$, then the problem is solved, and compactness is redundant.

Comment: I've come to the realization that some of my notation choices have obfuscated what's really going on here... What I *should* have said it my comment was that "the map $c\mapsto f_c(s)$ is continuous except at a single removable discontinuity."

So yes, it does indeed seem that my problem is solved!