# Can you integrate over a removable discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^4 x+2\ \mathrm{d}x = 16$$

$$\int_0^4 \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x = 16?$$

Comment: This is close to an improper integral, and I assume you approach this integral exactly the same way.

Comment: so you also have to do improper integration then? oh okay thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing removable discontinuities in Riemann integration](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313254/removing-removable-discontinuities-in-riemann-integration)

Comment: A bounded function on a bounded interval is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities has zero measure.

Comment: thats an analysis approach. which generalizes well I guess.

Comment: @PatrickStevens A removable singularity is not a discontinuity, it is a hole in the domain.

Comment: @Arthur We can define a new function which just gives the old function *any* value in that hole.

Comment: @user29418 I think the integral doesn't change, even if you remove one point.  Teacher wolfram say this interesting result.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB0+to+4+(x%5E2-4)%2F(x-2)dx

Comment: @PatrickStevens That's true, but then the integrand wouldn't be $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ any more. This question is about whether $\frac{x^2-4}{x+2}$ is integrable on an interval containing $2$, and changing the behaviour of the function at $2$ (like, say, giving function a value there) completely changes the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let introduce a few notations $\begin{cases} f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} \\ \tilde f(x)=x+2\ & \text{its continuous extension}\end{cases}$

$\displaystyle I_1(\varepsilon)=\int_0^{2-\varepsilon}f(x)dx=\int_0^{2-\varepsilon}\tilde f(x)dx=6-4\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2/2\to 6$

$\displaystyle I_2(\varepsilon)=\int_{2+\varepsilon}^4f(x)dx=\int_{2+\varepsilon}^4\tilde f(x)dx=10-4\varepsilon-\varepsilon^2/2\to 10$

Since $\tilde f$ is positive over $[0,4]$, it is clear that both $I_1(\varepsilon)$ and $I_2(\varepsilon)$ are increasing when $\varepsilon$ decreases toward zero.

It is also clear that $I_1(\varepsilon)\le 6$ and $I_2(\varepsilon)\le 10$ for $\varepsilon\ll 1$.

Now, it really depends of the theory of integration you choose.

From the results above, any method that agrees with the monotone convergence theorem (Beppo-Levi) will automatically agrees with $\displaystyle \int_0^4f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\ I_1(\varepsilon)+I_2(\varepsilon)=16$

This is the case for Lebesgue integral, as well as Riemann-complete integral (also known as Kurzweil-Henstock integral).

For Riemann integral, the integral over $[0,4]$ stays an improper-integral and it is a voluntary choice to extend it to $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\ I_1(\varepsilon)+I_2(\varepsilon)$ by continuity.

Note that the Lebesgue-like theorem that says that a function is Riemann integrable if its set of discontinuities is of measure zero, is a similar extension of the strict Riemann integration theory, and is also a voluntary choice to extend the value by continuity of the integral.

Comment: I would like to ask a question please. You wrote that the function is not Riemann integrable in the strict sense. But is it Darboux integrable? Thanks in advance.