# Prove that $\frac{x^5-x^4}{x^3-x^2}=x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry! It's bit childish math. But, somehow I can't derive what my book wrote. While doing integration I found following equation.

$$\int \frac{x^5-x^4}{x^3-x^2} dx$$
My process :

$$\int (x^5-x^4)(x^{-3}-x^{-2}) dx$$
$$\int x^2-x^3-x+x^2$$

But, my book wrote that first equation is equal to
$$\int x^2 dx$$

How? So, I can write that $(x^5-x^4)(x^{3}-x^{-2})^{-1}$, can't I? But, how can I move further? It's like I completely forgot algebra. :(

Comment: What do you get when you multiply $(x^3-x^2)$ by $x^2$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^3-x^2}\neq x^{-3}-x^{-2}$. Its like the same as saying $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$

Comment: @basilisk :thinking $\frac{1}{x^3-x^2}=\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}=x^{-3}-x^{-2}$

Comment: @lstiak: Consider  $\frac{1}{6-5}$ vs $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{5}$. The first is $1$; the second ... isn't. (This is all a reminder that, often, the hardest part of learning Calculus is remembering the stuff you learned *before* Calculus.)

Comment: @Joe Ohh! got it.

Comment: @Istiak $$\frac{x^5-x^4}{x^3-x^2}=\frac{x^4(x-1)}{x^2(x-1)}=x^{4-2}=x^2 \\ x≠0,x≠1$$

Comment: @lonestudent Ohh! Thanks

Comment: @Blue I am not a calculus expert. Can you explain me, why these integrals must be equal, becase in the first case we must accept $x≠0,x≠1$. Thank you.

Comment: This is what we call removable or artificial singularities, if the resulting function ($x^2$) is continuous in $0$ and $1$ then the integral is the same because the antiderivative is continuous (so value on $(0,1)$ is same than on $[0,1]$).  See $\to$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2212733/399263

Comment: @lonestudent: The $x\neq0$ and $x\neq1$ conditions are important algebraically. They correspond to "holes" (as opposed to, say, asymptotic singularities) in the graph of the function. However, if you consider the area-under-a-curve notion of the integral, the curve having a couple of *infinitesimal* glitches won't affect the computed area. A bit more (though not completely) formally, those holes amount to "removable discontinuities" (because the *limits* as $x\to0$ and $x\to1$ fill the holes), which the integral safely ignores.

Comment: @lone student, both functions agree where they are defined, and their domains only differ by two points, which in measure theory is referred to as a set of "measure zero", which informally means it makes no difference. In basic calc, one example would be that there's no difference between integrating a function over the closed interval $[a,b]$, and integrating the same function over the open interval $(a,b)$. Informally, the "area" under the end points is zero.

Comment: @Blue Many thanks for explanations. I'm trying to understand.